# Matrix crop (remove leading and trailing zeroes in matrix)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I have some matrices that have 0's around them, for example, give such a matrix

```
MatrixForm[ mat = ArrayPad[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}]]
```

> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}

Expect to get `{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}`.
One way is to use image processing,   but it's inefficient

```
ImageData[ImageCrop[Image[mat]]] // Round
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}

`Do[ImageData[ImageCrop[Image[mat, "Real"]]] // Round, 10^3] // AbsoluteTiming`

Might there be a faster method?

Comment: Have you already seen https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ArrayCrop/ ?

Comment: `Take[mat,##]&@@CoordinateBounds@SparseArray[mat]@"NonzeroPositions"`

Comment: @chyanog Wow, this is really fast, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 11):

```
matrixCrop[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
  Take[mat, ##] & @@ CoordinateBounds@SparseArray[mat]@"NonzeroPositions";

MatrixForm[mat = ArrayPad[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}]]
Do[matrixCrop[mat], 10^5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.694102, Null}

Answer (score 7):

If the *core* matrix isn't large, the following should be efficient:

```
RepeatedTiming@
 Normal@With[{m = SparseArray@mat}, 
   m[[##]] & @@ Span @@@ MinMax /@ Transpose@m@"ExplicitPositions"]
(* {0.0000115352, {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}} *)
```

If the *core* is large, the following should not be bad:

```
pos = m |-> Position[m, Except@{0 ..}, {1}, 1, Heads -> False][[1, 1]];
mat[[pos@mat ;; -pos@Reverse@mat, 
     pos[mat\[Transpose]] ;; -pos@Reverse[mat\[Transpose]]]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0000268782, {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

If there is a built-in function, surely someone will bring it up, but in any case, here is one implementation:

```
aux1[{}]={};
aux1[l_List]:=If[MatchQ[First[l],{0...}],aux1[Rest[l]],l];
aux2[l_List]:=Reverse[aux1[Reverse[aux1[l]]]];
crop[m_?MatrixQ]:=Transpose[aux2[Transpose[aux2[m]]]];
```

It works in your example

```
crop[mat]
(* {{1,2,3},{0,0,0},{7,8,0}} *)
```

**Warning:** I have not thought much about how this works with edge cases, matrices that are identically zero, numeric matrices, sparse arrays and all of that. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = ArrayPad[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}];
```

---

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
With[{c = Span @@ MinMax[Last /@ Position[mat, _?(# != 0 &)]]},
      #[[c]] & /@ Last@Sort @ SequenceSplit[mat, 
      s : {a_List /; Norm[a] != 0, __, b_List /; Norm[b] != 0} :> s]] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  7 & 8 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = ArrayPad[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}];
```

Positions of non-zero elements

```
p = Position[mat, x_ /; x != 0]
```

> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}}

Rows

```
r = Span @@ MinMax[First /@ p]
```

> 2 ;; 4

Columns

```
c = Span @@ MinMax[Last /@ p]
```

> 3 ;; 5

```
mat[[r, c]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

As oneliner

```
mat[[Span @@ MinMax[First /@ #], Span @@ MinMax[Last /@ #]]] &[
  Position[mat, x_ /; x != 0]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]